# UX Maturity Assessment results

Tags: research, ux-maturity

There are plenty of UX Maturity Assessment models at the moment, probably because of the different types of organisations they have been adapted for, and also because of the changing nature of UX design.

My question is: **are there known published *results* for assessments** being done for any UX Maturity models that are publicly available?

It would be interesting to see if that they are published or not, especially if the aim is to help assess and improve the quality of UX capabilities within organisations, the same way that NPS scores are used to determine level of customer service/experience provided.

Comment: I'm sure you've already seen this https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-maturity-stages-1-4/

Comment: @DarrylGodden I have, but I am not sure if they mention anything about a particular organisation's maturity level based on this criteria.

Comment: You used the phrase "assessments being done for any UX Maturity models" - are you looking for assessments of the models themselves, or just the results of assessments using the models? In either case, this seems like a big ask. Been pulling out all my Google Fu moves and actual results aren't popping up. Makes me wonder why a company (in general) would be motivated to publish something like this. Some startup measuring 6-7 on the NNG scale I can see, that's marketing material, but most of the time, the results are apt to be perceived in terms of how UX mature a company _isn't_.

Comment: @dennislees I assume that this is like the NPS scores that is released about companies, in which it is something that they can use for PR purposes? Where did you see these startups measuring 6-7 on the NNG scale?

Comment: I haven't seen any results at all. Perhaps I should have said "Some startup measuring 6-7 on the NNG scale I can _understand_", as in, I can understand why a company with a high score (as a user-driven startup) would want to publish results like this, but my guess is that most organizations aren't scoring 6-7, and so might be less likely to publish the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think NN/G's model is one of the most comprehensive ones that make sense and cover all the different level. There is a series of articles on that (as someone mentioned in the comments) explaining the 8 stages.

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-maturity-stages-1-4/

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-maturity-stages-5-8/

However more specifically, I participated in one of NN/Gs seminars and they explained at length what the different stages mean and what they entail for a company. **They even provided a survey for us participants to fill in that would help us figure out at which level our company's UX maturity stands.** This is probably closest to what you need and would probably help you to define your organisation's UX maturity (at least by NN/G's standards).

As an example, according to the survey, Facebook was at stage 8 on that scale.

Beyond that, the main gist was that it takes time to go through the 8 stages, years and decades even, but those time limits can be affected by a ux-centric management presence or someone higher up that is willing to make the switch into a more UX friendly structure.

Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to share that seminar material with you and I cannot seem to find the survey anywhere online.

However you can find multiple sources around the net that give a decent indication. I hope this info is helpful somewhat and can give you a better perspective.

Comment: Hi Socrates, your suggestion that _"you can find multiple sources around the net that give a decent indication"_ is the crux of this question. Michael's question is "Where are the sources?" and your answer is essentially "Sources exist, you can find them". Given the number of views on this question, and the bounty aspect, I imagine there are several technically minded people searching for anything related to this topic and coming up with nothing. Can you point out some of these sources you refer to?

Comment: Hi Dennis, you are right. 

I apologise for sounding so superficial and perhaps not too helpful. I know for a fact that NN/G has created that survey that allows you to judge the UX Maturity of your company but I have not encountered it outside the seminar. And even then the results where compiled in a graph by NN/G at the end of that session. Guessing due to copyright / paid seminar reasons.

That's the extend of all I know. Maybe attending one of these seminars is the answer.

Beyond that, if my answer is deemed not useful I will gladly remove it.

Comment: @SocratesKolios the comments are rather useful and provides some clues to where I might find the information I am looking for.

Comment: @dennislees Thanks also to your comment. Do you also have any answers or ideas on this?

Comment: I've spent some time searching and haven't come up with anything.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [in-depth article from MeasuringU](https://measuringu.com/ux-maturity/) stating this **lack of empirical studies** for these models.

> It’s not clear how these models were developed so practitioners are left to assume that authors have largely derived them through their own professional experiences rather than using empirical methods.

They have recently published an article for CHI EA '17 **describing their case study**.

[From Snake-Oil to Science: Measuring UX Maturity](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3053350)

> [...] This case study describes the first steps into an empirically derived maturity model and describes what we've learned from interviewing seasoned UX professionals and surveying practitioners from dozens of organizations. [...]

Comment: +1 Some really good references, hopefully there will be more information available soon.

Answer (score 2):

Along with everyone else I had a good Google around, and the results are slim!

The best I could find are from Denmark (thank you, Google Translate), from 2016. The two case studies are here:

- [Business Use and Design Needs](http://danskdesigncenter.dk/da/virksomheders-brug-af-og-behov-design)
- [Exploring Design Impact](http://danskdesigncenter.dk/da/exploring-design-impact-designs-vaerdiskabelse-i-danske-virksomheder)

They seem like a pretty comprehensive review of design use in Danish companies. Of course, the results are not necessarily cross-cultural, what with Denmark's history of good design, but it's a good starting point.

I found them through [this article on UX Maturity Models](https://nataliehanson.com/2017/02/13/ux-maturity-models/). I suspect it's not quite what you were after, as it doesn't strictly compare the companies against models, but it's certainly down the right road.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: appalling spelling!

Comment: +1 Some good references and possible leads... I guess it will require some further digging around.

Comment: I did read Natalie Hanson's article, and I understand she is also trying to propose her own ux maturity model. I would give you an extra upvote for using Google Translate but I can't :p

Answer (score 1):

To determine the UX Maturity of an organization, I found following sources that could be a step in the direction.

Eric Schaefer gives a checklist.
Slide 8 on this:
https://www.slideshare.net/ThomasCallaghan/ux-maturity-models-61688654

Team Engagement Score to measure UX Maturity
http://www.bentley.edu/files/2017/06/13/UXPA2017_Albert_Rosenberg_final.pdf

Comment: https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/6W7JW69

Comment: If you can please copy and paste some of the relevant information into your post.